# Setting ViewModel for MvxFragment

Tags: android, xamarin, fragment, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I am working on an application using **Xamarin.Android** and **MVVMCross** and I am running into some issues with trying to set the ViewModel (MvxViewModel) for a Fragment (MvxFragment).

In my research so far, I have found some examples but they seem to be pretty dated and, therefore, no longer useful.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3652/mvvmcross-activity-vs-fragment
http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/06/n26-fragments-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html

My specific situation is that I am trying to create an application with a drawerlayout which I have working just fine, the problem is that when I load an **MvxFragment** subclass via the **FragmentManager** the ViewModel is not being associated with the View (the ViewModel was correctly associated before I changed the View from a Activity to a Fragment.)

When I was looking up some documentation on how to do this, I found the following code

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment_Detail, null);
    }
```

the issue with this is that there is no method `BindingInflate(...)` in MvxFragment.

Here is what my OnCreateView looks like

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomeView, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

So my question boils down to: How do I associate my ViewModel with my View that is an extention of MVxFragment?

Not sure if this helps, but I am creating the Fragment like so

```
var fragment = new HomeView();
FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment).Commit();
```

Comment: I am working on MvxFragments and have some nice stuff working, such as a Fragment finding its own ViewModel. I is in my fork right now and I am finishing up a sample. This will of course be pulled into MvvmCross eventually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe that I missed this, but the solution was really simple. All I had to do was add this.

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext;
```